# Trying to set google maps marker using array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fiddling with the maps v3 API and I'm using some examples from the web to try and get some differing markers. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I'm going for a similar map as this one - the idea is to filter out community members by the game they play/own......

http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_sidebar2.html

So I've created my array very similar with just two entries:

```
var stationList = [
    {"latlng":[231.015,126.431],name:"membername1", battlefield4 : 1, warframe : 1, Ghosts : 1, Killzone: 0},
    {"latlng":[234.004,134.999],name:"membername2", battlefield4 : 1, warframe : 1, Ghosts : 1, Killzone: 1},
  ];
```

And the block code I'm editing is:

```
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var station, latlng;
    var image = './img/member.png'

    for ( i = 0; i < stationList.length; i++) {
      station = stationList[i];
      latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(station.latlng[0], station.latlng[1]);
      bounds.extend(latlng);

      var marker = createMarker({
        map : mapCanvas,
        position : latlng,
        others : station,
        icon: image
      });
```

At the moment this assigns a default icon to everyone and works well, but there are roles within the community that I'd like to represent differently. What I did was add an entry to the array as follows:

```
var stationList = [
    {"latlng":[51.515,-0.101],name:"membername1", battlefield4 : 1, warframe : 1, Ghosts : 1, Killzone: 0, image: "./img/founder.png"},
    {"latlng":[51.678,-0.205],name:"membername2", battlefield4 : 1, warframe : 1, Ghosts : 1, Killzone: 1, image: "./img/founder.png"},
  ];
```

And then edited the marker block as follows:

```
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var station, latlng;
    var image;

    for ( i = 0; i < stationList.length; i++) {
      station = stationList[i];
      latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(station.latlng[0], station.latlng[1]);
      bounds.extend(latlng);
      image = station.image;
      var marker = createMarker({
        map : mapCanvas,
        position : latlng,
        others : station,
        icon: image
      });
```

But it just seems to bomb the whole page out. I figure I'm not addressing the array properly or it's something to do with quotation marks etc. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: How about a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: It should be something else not shown in this part of code.